# Angular 8 - Unit Test Issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have been trying to identify the issue that is going on in here and I cannot figure out what is the issue or where name is causing the error either in the TS or the Spec.TS file. I need your assistance.

edit-task-dialog.component.ts file

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {SessionService} from '../../services/session.service';
import {DialogData} from '../tasks/tasks.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-task-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-task-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-task-dialog.component.css']
})
export class EditTaskDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  task: any;
  showActuals: boolean;

  scheduledStart;
  scheduledEnd;
  actualStart;
  actualEnd;
  selectedCategory = '';
  categories;
  minDate;
  minEndDate;
  timeRegex = /^(?:(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5]\d\s[AP][M])?$/;
  isWrongDate = false;

  nameFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
  ]);

  sDateFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
  ]);

  eDateFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
  ]);

  sTimeFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(this.timeRegex)
  ]);

  eTimeFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(this.timeRegex)
  ]);

  constructor(
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditTaskDialogComponent>,
      private http: HttpClient,
      private sessionService: SessionService,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.minEndDate = new Date();
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  onYesClick(): void {
    this.scheduledStart = this.dateConversion(this.task.ssTime, this.task.ssDate);
    this.scheduledEnd = this.dateConversion(this.task.seTime, this.task.seDate);
    // this.actualStart = this.dateConversion(this.task.asTime, this.task.asDate);
    // this.actualEnd = this.dateConversion(this.task.aeTime, this.task.aeDate);

    if (this.scheduledEnd < this.scheduledStart) {
      this.isWrongDate = true;
    } else {
      this.isWrongDate = false;

      const headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.sessionService.getToken()};

      const body = {
        id: this.task.id,
        name: this.task.name,
        description: this.task.description,
        category: this.task.category,
        scheduledStart: this.scheduledStart,
        scheduledEnd: this.scheduledEnd
        // actualstart: this.actualStart,
        // actualend: this.actualEnd

      };

      console.log('Log body before put: ', body);
      console.log('BEFORE put');
      this.http.put('http://localhost:8001/tasks/task', body, {headers}).subscribe({
        next: data => console.log(data),
        error: error => console.error('There was an error!', error)
      });


      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }

  onActualsClick(): void {
    this.showActuals = true;
    console.log('Actual click');
  }

  dateConversion(time: string, date: Date): Date {
     const tempDate = date;
     const tempTime = time;

     const parts = tempTime.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)/);
     if (parts) {
      let hours = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
      const  minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
      const tt = parts[3];
      if (tt === 'PM' && hours < 12) { hours += 12; }
      if (tt === 'AM' && hours === 12) {hours = 0; }
      // console.log("hours: ", hours);
      // console.log("minutes: ", minutes);
      // console.log("date: ", date);
      date.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);
    }

     return tempDate;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.showActuals = false;
    this.getCategory();

    this.id = this.data.id;

    this.task = this.data.task;

    setTimeout(() => {
      let date = this.task.scheduledstart.substring(0, this.task.scheduledstart.length - 5);
      const ssDate = new Date(date);
      const ssTime = ssDate.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
      this.task.ssTime = ssTime;
      this.task.ssDate = ssDate;

      date = this.task.scheduledEnd.substring(0, this.task.scheduledEnd.length - 5);
      const seDate = new Date(date);
      const seTime = seDate.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
      this.task.seTime = seTime;
      this.task.seDate = seDate;

    });

    console.log('The task: ', this.task);


  }

  getCategory(): void {

    const headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.sessionService.getToken()
    };

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8001/category/mine', { headers }).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.categories = data;
        console.log(this.categories);
      },
      error: error => console.error('There was an error!', error)
    });
  }

  changeMinEndDate() {
    this.minEndDate = this.task.ssDate;
  }
}
```

edit-task-dialog.component.spec.ts file

```
/** Linked Issue: TMGP4-32: Update Task
 *
 *  Author: Chavarria Leo
 *
 *  Unit Test - Frontend
 */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {CustomMaterialModule} from '../../modules/material.module';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AmplifyService} from 'aws-amplify-angular';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { EditTaskDialogComponent } from './edit-task-dialog.component';
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {SessionService} from '../../services/session.service';
import {DialogData} from '../tasks/tasks.component';
import {
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbar,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule
} from '@angular/material';

describe('EditTaskDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: EditTaskDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditTaskDialogComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        MatIconModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        CustomMaterialModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatDialogModule,


      ],
      providers: [AmplifyService, HttpClient, {
        provide: MatDialogRef,
        useValue: {}},
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {}}],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [ EditTaskDialogComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditTaskDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Here is the HTML File

```
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <h1 mat-dialog-title>Edit Task "{{task.name}}"</h1>
        <span class="example-spacer"></span>
        <button mat-button  (click)="onNoClick()">
            <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example user verified icon">close</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <form>
        <div fxLayout="column">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.name" name="taskName" [formControl]="nameFormControl">
                <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
                    Name is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>


            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="task.category" name="taskCat">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.name">
                        {{category.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.description" name="taskDesc">
            </mat-form-field>`enter code here`

        </div>


        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
            <div fxFlex="">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [min]="minDate" [(ngModel)]="task.ssDate" name="taskSDate"
                           [formControl]="sDateFormControl" (dateChange)="changeMinEndDate()">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="sDateFormControl.hasError('required')">
                        Start Date is <strong>required</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="" fxLayoutGap="15px">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Start Time</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.ssTime" name="taskssTime" [formControl]="sTimeFormControl">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="sTimeFormControl.hasError('required')">
                        Start Time is <strong>required</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="sTimeFormControl.hasError('pattern')"> Start Time must follow <strong>HH:MM PM|AM</strong> format
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="15px">
            <div fxFlex="">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>End date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" [(ngModel)]="task.seDate" name="taskseDate"
                           [min]="minEndDate" [formControl]="eDateFormControl">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="eDateFormControl.hasError('required')">
                        End Date is <strong>required</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="" fxLayoutGap="15px">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.seTime" name="taskseTime" [formControl]="eTimeFormControl" [disabled]="true">

                    <mat-error *ngIf="eTimeFormControl.hasError('required')"> End Time is <strong>required</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="eTimeFormControl.hasError('pattern')"> End Time must follow <strong>HH:MM PM|AM</strong> format
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--        <button mat-button (click)="onActualsClick()" *ngIf="!showActuals"> Edit actuals <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Edit actual times icon">edit</mat-icon></button>-->

<!--        <div *ngIf="showActuals">-->
<!--            <mat-divider></mat-divider>-->
<!--            <p style="color:purple; !important">Actual Times</p>-->
<!--            <div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="15px">-->
<!--                <div fxFlex="">-->
<!--                    <mat-form-field>-->
<!--                        <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>-->
<!--                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker3" [(ngModel)]="task.asDate" name="taskasDate"-->
<!--                               [formControl]="sDateFormControl" >-->
<!--                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>-->
<!--                        <mat-datepicker #picker3></mat-datepicker>-->
<!--                        <mat-error *ngIf="sDateFormControl.hasError('required')">-->
<!--                            Start Date is <strong>required</strong>-->
<!--                        </mat-error>-->
<!--                    </mat-form-field>-->
<!--                </div>-->
<!--                <div fxFlex="" >-->
<!--                    <mat-form-field>-->
<!--                        <mat-label>Start Time</mat-label>-->
<!--                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.asTime" name="taskasTime" [formControl]="sTimeFormControl">-->
<!--                        <mat-error *ngIf="sTimeFormControl.hasError('required')">-->
<!--                            Start Time is <strong>required</strong>-->
<!--                        </mat-error>-->
<!--                        <mat-error *ngIf="sTimeFormControl.hasError('pattern')"> Start Time must follow <strong>HH:MM PM|AM</strong> format-->
<!--                        </mat-error>-->
<!--                    </mat-form-field>-->
<!--                </div>-->
<!--            </div>-->

<!--            <div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="15px">-->
<!--                <div fxFlex="" >-->
<!--                    <mat-form-field>-->
<!--                        <mat-label>End date</mat-label>-->
<!--                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker4" [(ngModel)]="task.aeDate" name="taskaeDate" [formControl]="eDateFormControl">-->
<!--                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker4"></mat-datepicker-toggle>-->
<!--                        <mat-datepicker #picker4></mat-datepicker>-->
<!--                        <mat-error *ngIf="eDateFormControl.hasError('required')">-->
<!--                            End Date is <strong>required</strong>-->
<!--                        </mat-error>-->
<!--                    </mat-form-field>-->
<!--                </div>-->
<!--                <div fxFlex="">-->
<!--                    <mat-form-field>-->
<!--                        <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>-->
<!--                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.aeTime" name="taskaeTime">-->
<!--                </div>-->
<!--            </div>-->
<!--        </div>-->
    </form>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end" class="header-text">
    <mat-error *ngIf="isWrongDate"> End date and time should be later than start date and time.
    </mat-error>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onYesClick()" cdkFocusInitial
            [disabled]="!eTimeFormControl.valid || !sTimeFormControl.valid || !eDateFormControl.valid ||
            !sDateFormControl.valid || !nameFormControl.valid">Save</button>
</div>
```

Error that I get - I am also using WebStorm and a configuration of Karma

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 939514883, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: -268894785, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 650887171, directChildFlags: 4243457, childMatchedQueries: 2, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 13, bindings: [ Object({ flags: 2, ns: '', name: 'mat-toolbar-multiple-rows', nonMinifiedName: 'mat-toolbar-multiple-rows', securityContext: undefined, suffix: undefined }), Object({ flags: 2, ns: '', name: 'mat-toolbar-single-row', nonMinifiedName: 'mat-toolbar-single-row', securityContext: undefined, suffix: undefined }) ], bindingFlags: 2, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'mat-toolbar', attrs: [ Array, Array, Array ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent:  ...
>       at

Comment: Your details are not sufficient, though check your component.html there might be some name property assigned for which you have declared a private property in your Component.ts, just a random guess please try let me know if ot got fixed

Comment: I think, this.data.task is causing the issue. Where you have declared data? and you are trying to get task from this.data. this.task = this.data.task. Some thing wrong here. Is the component working? Did you check console when run the application?

Comment: I will be adding the HTML to see if this helps.

Comment: what's the console output of your console.log('The task : ', this.task)? It sounds like your task isn't correctly initialized inside the ngOnInit. Check data.task too

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the HTML file with the original post and would like to get some assistance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some form are not has initialized in the tests. You need to mock a service that bring the data .. or you can find the form that are not initialized and set a value for him in these part of code:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditTaskDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    /*component.eDateFormControl ={new Date()}  --form not initialized */
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```